# C# Desktop Application: SQL Server access suddenly gets slow

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, slowdown

My C# desktop application has a form `ItemsBrowser`. My application is about an Inventory system. The `ItemsBrowser` form loads the Items Details while user add a new sale or new purchase. Here is `LoadAllItems()` code: -

```
    void LoadAllItems()
    {
        DBConnector dbc = new DBConnector();
        AccountsBasic.Classes.DBConnector dbca = new AccountsBasic.Classes.DBConnector();
        ArrayList lstItems = dbc.GetAllItems();
        var AddedItems = new List<DataGridViewRow>();

        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        dgvItems.Rows.Clear();
        for (int i=0; i<=lstItems.Count-1; i++)
        {
            Item itm = (Item)lstItems[i];
            ItemCategory ItemCat = dbc.GetThisItemCategory(itm.ItemCategoryCode);
            DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
            row.CreateCells(dgvItems);              
            row.Cells[0].Value = dbca.GetThisParty(dbc.GetThisItemCategory(itm.ItemCategoryCode).SupplierCode).PartyName;
            row.Cells[1].Value = ItemCat.ItemCategoryName;
            row.Cells[2].Value = itm.ItemID.ToString();
            row.Cells[3].Value = itm.ItemName;
            row.Cells[4].Value = itm.RetailPrice.ToString();
            row.Cells[5].Value = dbc.GetPresentStock_By_ItemID(itm.ItemID).ToString();

            AddedItems.Add(row);
            //dgvItems.Rows.Add(dbca.GetThisParty(dbc.GetThisItemCategory(itm.ItemCategoryCode).SupplierCode).PartyName, dbc.GetThisItemCategory(itm.ItemCategoryCode).ItemCategoryName, itm.ItemID.ToString(), itm.ItemName, itm.RetailPrice, dbc.GetPresentStock_By_ItemID(itm.ItemID).ToString());
        }

        dgvItems.Rows.AddRange(AddedItems.ToArray());
        dgvItems.AutoResizeColumns();
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

This function was working fine and in speed. But suddenly It got slow very much. By checking each line one by one in the loop, I found that when a statement accessing the database like 
`ItemCategory ItemCat = dbc.GetThisItemCategory(itm.ItemCategoryCode);`
the database access gets very slow. Although it was running pretty fine before. There are total 955 items in the table.

ALSO A VERY STRANGE THING I HAVE NOTICED...

I have installed this application on the client's machine and it is working fine there on client's machine with no delay...

GetAllItems() Function

```
public ArrayList GetAllItems(string SupplierCode = "", string ItemCategory = "")
{
    if (SupplierCode != "" && ItemCategory != "")
        comm.CommandText = "SELECT Items.ItemID, Items.ItemName, Items.Description, Items.ItemCategoryCode, Items.OpeningStock, Items.RetailPrice FROM Items, ItemCategories WHERE Items.ItemCategoryCode = ItemCategories.ItemCategoryCode AND ItemCategories.SupplierCode = '" + SupplierCode + "' AND ItemCategories.ItemCategory = '" + ItemCategory + "' ORDER BY Items.ItemID";
    else if (SupplierCode != "" && ItemCategory == "")
        comm.CommandText = "SELECT Items.ItemID, Items.ItemName, Items.Description, Items.ItemCategoryCode, Items.OpeningStock, Items.RetailPrice FROM Items, ItemCategories WHERE Items.ItemCategoryCode = ItemCategories.ItemCategoryCode AND ItemCategories.SupplierCode = '" + SupplierCode + "' ORDER BY ItemCategories.SupplierCode, ItemCategories.ItemCategory";
    else if (SupplierCode == "" && ItemCategory != "")
        comm.CommandText = "SELECT Items.ItemID, Items.ItemName, Items.Description, Items.ItemCategoryCode, Items.OpeningStock, Items.RetailPrice FROM Items, ItemCategories WHERE Items.ItemCategoryCode = ItemCategories.ItemCategoryCode AND ItemCategories.ItemCategory = '" + ItemCategory + "' ORDER BY Items.ItemID";
    else
        comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Items Order By ItemID";

    ArrayList AllItems = new ArrayList();
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr;
    dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        Item it = new Item();
        it.ItemID = dr.GetInt32(0);
        it.ItemName = dr.GetString(1);
        it.Description = dr.IsDBNull(2) ? "" : dr.GetString(2);
        it.ItemCategoryCode = dr.IsDBNull(3) ? -1 : dr.GetInt32(3);
        it.OpeningStock = dr.IsDBNull(4) ? 0 : dr.GetInt32(4);
        it.RetailPrice = dr.IsDBNull(5) ? 0 : dr.GetDouble(5);

        AllItems.Add(it);
    }
    dr.Close();
    conn.Close();

    return AllItems;
}
```

GetThisItemCategory() Function

```
    public ItemCategory GetThisItemCategory(int ItemCategoryCode = -1, string SupplierCode = "", string ItemCategory = "")
{
    if (ItemCategoryCode == -1 && SupplierCode != "" && ItemCategory != "")
        comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ItemCategories WHERE SupplierCode = '" + SupplierCode + "' AND ItemCategory = '" + ItemCategory + "' Order By SupplierCode, ItemCategory";
    else if (ItemCategoryCode == -1 && SupplierCode == "" && ItemCategory != "")
        comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ItemCategories WHERE ItemCategory = '" + ItemCategory + "' Order By ItemCategory";
    else// if (ItemCategoryCode != -1 && SupplierCode == "" && ItemCategory == "")
        comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ItemCategories WHERE ItemCategoryCode = '" + ItemCategoryCode + "' Order By SupplierCode, ItemCategory";

    SqlDataReader dr;
    ItemCategory ic = new ItemCategory();
    ic.ItemCategoryCode = -1;

    conn.Open();
    dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        ic.ItemCategoryCode = dr.GetInt32(0);
        ic.SupplierCode = dr.GetString(1);
        ic.ItemCategoryName = dr.GetString(2);
        ic.OrderableStockLimit = (dr.IsDBNull(3)) ? -1 : dr.GetInt32(3);
    }
    dr.Close();
    conn.Close();

    return ic;
}
```

Actually, problem is not about specific function. It is about any database access, whether it is GetThisItemCategory() or GetPresentStock_By_ItemID() function.

PLEASE NOTE EARLIER IT WAS WORKING PRETTY FINE. SUDDENLY IT STARTED BEHAVING IN THIS MANNER...

Comment: Run Sql Server profiler, catch actual query being executed at SQL server when `GetThisItemCategory` method is being called. Then run this query at server. If execution time is about the same - you need to find the way to improve that query performance (probably creating some indexes and so on), Otherwise it is some problem with your `DBConnector`.

Comment: What is the logic of GetThisItemCategory function and dbc.GetAllItems() function?

Comment: Have provided the code of GetThisItemCategory() and GetAllItems() functions...

Comment: Would it be an issue of Network Card?

Comment: Using Sql Server profiler, it took 1 minute and 12 seconds time to complete the task.

Comment: Grab the query from sql profiler, put it in SSMS....and then look at the "EXECUTION PLAN" for the query.  You need to do basic tuning.  Things like "Table scan" are bad.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn how to do "named parameters", to protect against injected sql attacks AND to get maximum plan-reuse from your RDBMS.

Here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

class ParamDemo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // conn and reader declared outside try
        // block for visibility in finally block
        SqlConnection conn   = null;
        SqlDataReader reader = null;

        string inputCity = "London";
        try
        {
            // instantiate and open connection
            conn =  new 
                SqlConnection("Server=(local);DataBase=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI");
            conn.Open();

            // don't ever do this
            // SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
            // "select * from Customers where city = '" + inputCity + "'";

            // 1. declare command object with parameter
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                "select * from Customers where city = @City", conn);

            // 2. define parameters used in command object
            SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@City";
            param.Value         = inputCity;

            // 3. add new parameter to command object
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

            // get data stream
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            // write each record
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", 
                    reader["CompanyName"], 
                    reader["ContactName"]);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // close reader
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.Close();
            }

            // close connection
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06

You can read a few things about dynamic sql in this article.

http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/don-t-fear-dynamic-sql

(There is a mini overlap between your .cs C# "inline" sql vs this article...it'll give you a few things to research further if you're inclined)

.....

Finally, you need to learn the basics of "index tuning".

You can get an intro to that here:

https://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/a-dmv-a-day-%E2%80%93-day-7/

As a guess,  I would create an index on

> ItemCategories.ItemCategoryCode

and a seperate index on

> ItemCategories.SupplierCode

APPEND:

Finally, can you try this version of the code?

You want to get-rid of DataReaders as soon as possible, so your connection pool does not run out of connections.

```
public ItemCategory GetThisItemCategory(int ItemCategoryCode = -1, string SupplierCode = "", string ItemCategory = "")
{

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MyConnectionString")
    {

        /* TO DO !!! , build your sql-string and parameter list here */

        using (IDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
        {

            if /*while*/ (dataReader.Read())
            {
                ic.ItemCategoryCode = dr.GetInt32(0);
                ic.SupplierCode = dr.GetString(1);
                ic.ItemCategoryName = dr.GetString(2);
                ic.OrderableStockLimit = (dr.IsDBNull(3)) ? -1 : dr.GetInt32(3);
            }

            if (dataReader != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    dataReader.Close();
                }
                catch { }
            }           

        }

        cmd.Close();

    }

    return ic;

}
```

Comment: Does using parameters in SQL query improves performance and data reading speed?

Comment: Read the sqlmag article.  Then code up the parameters and look at the sql in sql-profiler.  You should see that the code (now sent) to sql-server talks about the best practices of the sqlmag article.

Comment: Thanks @granadaCoder